# What to do if the chapter is too short and needs something but it just seems to stop?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, chapters

I have a few chapters in the novel I'm writing, and it seems that they just end randomly. I feel there needs to be more to the story, but I either ran out of ideas or it really doesn't need anything. But the fact of the matter is, that the empty pages are really adding to my "book stress".

Does anyone have any good suggestions of how to fix this?

Comment: I feel like the answers to this question might help you: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/when-should-a-chapter-end?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: that - that helped.

Comment: In that case, this'll probably get closed as a duplicate, but I'm glad I could help!