# How long is a typical chapter?

Tags: publishing, formatting

I'm using Google Docs to make my first attempt at writing a novel (aka destroying my soul). I'm using 12pt Times New Roman, double spaced. I'm interested in how many pages in that format would make up a typical chapter?

I feel like I'm at a decent stopping point, but I don't know if I have enough. I've got about 5 pages written currently.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Writers SE!  Unfortunately, your question appears to be a duplicate of a question I linked in the above comment.  I would suggest to read through that question first and if you still don't find the solution you are looking for, try to modify this question some as it appears to be the same question.

Comment: You can also check out [What is a normal length for a chapter](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-is-a-normal-length-for-a-chapter) as this also may cover what you are looking for!

Comment: How long are the chapters in the books you read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no common length for a chapter. It depends on the formatting and the contents of the chapter. A good stopping point is when your story hits a hook that leaves your reader wanting to read the next chapter.

I suggest reading a book or two and notice how the author smoothly transitions from one chapter to the next. You'll notice that the author leaves the reader wanting more, and that "more" can only be found when the reader starts the next chapter.

Good luck!